# Ошибка в подключении контроллера в Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Я гуглил перед тем как задать вопрос, тема похожая есть, однако решение в ней не помогли

Суть проблемы: создал контроллер в Laravel и пытаюсь его подключить, пишет, что он не найдет, вот собственно ошибка Illuminate\ Contracts\ Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [MyPlaceController] does not exist.

```
web.php

<?php

use Illuminate\Routing\Route as RoutingRoute;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\MyPlaceController;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/my', 'MyPlaceController@index');



MyPlaceController.php


<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class MyPlaceController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return 'This is my page';
    }
}
```

По всей видимости косячу с namespace и с use, пока не до конца понимаю как огни работают!

Answer (score 0):

Да я Сам разобрался, пришлось покурить доку по Laravel, в общем ошибка была в том, что использовал синтаксис не верно,а именно Route::get('/my', 'MyPlaceController@index');
заменить на Route::get('/my', [MyPlaceController,'index']);

Видимо Laravel 9, курсы по которому я просматриваю отличается синтаксисом от Laravel 10 в этой части!